# RestSharp Not Deserializing all Values

Tags: c#, deserialization, restsharp

I am having inaccurate Deserialization results from RestSharp
The fields **TodaysCases** and **TodaysDeaths** are always deserializing as '0'
What is the issue?

```
var client = new RestClient("https://corona.lmao.ninja/countries");
var response = client.Execute<List<CountryItem>>(new RestRequest());
```

Class

```
public class CountryItem
{
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "country")]
        public string Country { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "cases")]
        public int Cases { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "todaysCases")]
        public int TodaysCases { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "deaths")]
        public int Deaths { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "todaysDeaths")]
        public int TodaysDeaths { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "critical")]
        public int Critical { get; set; }
```

**Json**

```
[
   {
      "country":"China",
      "cases":80881,
      "todayCases":21,
      "deaths":3226,
      "todayDeaths":13,
      "recovered":68690,
      "critical":3226
   },
   {
      "country":"Italy",
      "cases":27980,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":2158,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":2749,
      "critical":1851
   },
   {
      "country":"Iran",
      "cases":14991,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":853,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":4996,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Spain",
      "cases":9942,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":342,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":530,
      "critical":272
   },
   {
      "country":"S. Korea",
      "cases":8320,
      "todayCases":84,
      "deaths":81,
      "todayDeaths":6,
      "recovered":1401,
      "critical":59
   },
   {
      "country":"Germany",
      "cases":7272,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":17,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":67,
      "critical":2
   },
   {
      "country":"France",
      "cases":6633,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":148,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":12,
      "critical":400
   },
   {
      "country":"USA",
      "cases":4727,
      "todayCases":64,
      "deaths":93,
      "todayDeaths":7,
      "recovered":74,
      "critical":12
   },
   {
      "country":"Switzerland",
      "cases":2353,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":19,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":4,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"UK",
      "cases":1543,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":55,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":52,
      "critical":20
   },
   {
      "country":"Netherlands",
      "cases":1413,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":24,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":2,
      "critical":45
   },
   {
      "country":"Norway",
      "cases":1348,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":3,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":1,
      "critical":27
   },
   {
      "country":"Sweden",
      "cases":1121,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":7,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":1,
      "critical":2
   },
   {
      "country":"Belgium",
      "cases":1058,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":10,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":1,
      "critical":33
   },
   {
      "country":"Austria",
      "cases":1018,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":3,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":8,
      "critical":12
   },
   {
      "country":"Denmark",
      "cases":914,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":4,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":1,
      "critical":10
   },
   {
      "country":"Japan",
      "cases":833,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":28,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":144,
      "critical":41
   },
   {
      "country":"Diamond Princess",
      "cases":696,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":7,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":456,
      "critical":15
   },
   {
      "country":"Malaysia",
      "cases":566,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":42,
      "critical":9
   },
   {
      "country":"Canada",
      "cases":441,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":4,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":11,
      "critical":1
   },
   {
      "country":"Australia",
      "cases":440,
      "todayCases":39,
      "deaths":5,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":27,
      "critical":1
   },
   {
      "country":"Qatar",
      "cases":439,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":4,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Greece",
      "cases":352,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":4,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":8,
      "critical":5
   },
   {
      "country":"Czechia",
      "cases":344,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":3,
      "critical":2
   },
   {
      "country":"Portugal",
      "cases":331,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":1,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":3,
      "critical":18
   },
   {
      "country":"Israel",
      "cases":298,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":4,
      "critical":4
   },
   {
      "country":"Finland",
      "cases":278,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":10,
      "critical":1
   },
   {
      "country":"Slovenia",
      "cases":253,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":1,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":3
   },
   {
      "country":"Singapore",
      "cases":243,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":109,
      "critical":11
   },
   {
      "country":"Brazil",
      "cases":234,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":2,
      "critical":2
   },
   {
      "country":"Bahrain",
      "cases":228,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":1,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":81,
      "critical":1
   },
   {
      "country":"Ireland",
      "cases":223,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":2,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":5,
      "critical":6
   },
   {
      "country":"Estonia",
      "cases":205,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":1,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Iceland",
      "cases":199,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":1
   },
   {
      "country":"Pakistan",
      "cases":184,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":1,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":2,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Poland",
      "cases":177,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":4,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":3
   },
   {
      "country":"Romania",
      "cases":168,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":9,
      "critical":2
   },
   {
      "country":"Egypt",
      "cases":166,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":4,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":32,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Hong Kong",
      "cases":157,
      "todayCases":2,
      "deaths":4,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":81,
      "critical":4
   },
   {
      "country":"Chile",
      "cases":156,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Thailand",
      "cases":147,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":1,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":35,
      "critical":1
   },
   {
      "country":"Philippines",
      "cases":142,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":12,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":5,
      "critical":1
   },
   {
      "country":"Indonesia",
      "cases":134,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":5,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":8,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Iraq",
      "cases":133,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":10,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":32,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Saudi Arabia",
      "cases":133,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":6,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"India",
      "cases":129,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":3,
      "todayDeaths":1,
      "recovered":13,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Kuwait",
      "cases":123,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":9,
      "critical":4
   },
   {
      "country":"San Marino",
      "cases":109,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":7,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":4,
      "critical":11
   },
   {
      "country":"Lebanon",
      "cases":109,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":3,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":3,
      "critical":3
   },
   {
      "country":"UAE",
      "cases":98,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":23,
      "critical":2
   },
   {
      "country":"Russia",
      "cases":93,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":8,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Peru",
      "cases":86,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":1,
      "critical":8
   },
   {
      "country":"Mexico",
      "cases":82,
      "todayCases":29,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":4,
      "critical":1
   },
   {
      "country":"Luxembourg",
      "cases":81,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":1,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":10
   },
   {
      "country":"Slovakia",
      "cases":72,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Panama",
      "cases":69,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":1,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Taiwan",
      "cases":67,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":1,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":20,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Argentina",
      "cases":65,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":2,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":3,
      "critical":1
   },
   {
      "country":"South Africa",
      "cases":64,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Bulgaria",
      "cases":62,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":2,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Vietnam",
      "cases":61,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":16,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Algeria",
      "cases":60,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":4,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":10,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Ecuador",
      "cases":58,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":2,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":2
   },
   {
      "country":"Croatia",
      "cases":57,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":3,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Serbia",
      "cases":57,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":1,
      "critical":2
   },
   {
      "country":"Brunei",
      "cases":54,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":1
   },
   {
      "country":"Colombia",
      "cases":54,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":1,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Armenia",
      "cases":52,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":1,
      "critical":2
   },
   {
      "country":"Albania",
      "cases":51,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":1,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":2
   },
   {
      "country":"Turkey",
      "cases":47,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Cyprus",
      "cases":46,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":1
   },
   {
      "country":"Costa Rica",
      "cases":41,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":3
   },
   {
      "country":"Hungary",
      "cases":39,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":1,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":2,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Palestine",
      "cases":39,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Morocco",
      "cases":37,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":1,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":1,
      "critical":1
   },
   {
      "country":"Belarus",
      "cases":36,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":3,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Latvia",
      "cases":34,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":1,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Georgia",
      "cases":33,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":1,
      "critical":1
   },
   {
      "country":"Venezuela",
      "cases":33,
      "todayCases":16,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Malta",
      "cases":30,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":2,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Jordan",
      "cases":29,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":1,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Moldova",
      "cases":29,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":1,
      "critical":1
   },
   {
      "country":"Uruguay",
      "cases":29,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Sri Lanka",
      "cases":28,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":1,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Senegal",
      "cases":27,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":2,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Azerbaijan",
      "cases":25,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":1,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":6,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Bosnia and Herzegovina",
      "cases":25,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":2,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Cambodia",
      "cases":24,
      "todayCases":12,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":1,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"North Macedonia",
      "cases":24,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":1,
      "critical":1
   },
   {
      "country":"Oman",
      "cases":24,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":9,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Tunisia",
      "cases":24,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":2
   },
   {
      "country":"Dominican Republic",
      "cases":21,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":1,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Afghanistan",
      "cases":21,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":1,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Lithuania",
      "cases":18,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":1,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Faeroe Islands",
      "cases":18,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Martinique",
      "cases":15,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":1,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Burkina Faso",
      "cases":15,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Andorra",
      "cases":14,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Kazakhstan",
      "cases":13,
      "todayCases":3,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Maldives",
      "cases":13,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Macao",
      "cases":12,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":10,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Jamaica",
      "cases":12,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":2,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"New Zealand",
      "cases":11,
      "todayCases":3,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Bolivia",
      "cases":11,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"French Guiana",
      "cases":11,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Monaco",
      "cases":9,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Réunion",
      "cases":9,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Guatemala",
      "cases":8,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":1,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Bangladesh",
      "cases":8,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":3,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Paraguay",
      "cases":8,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":1
   },
   {
      "country":"Uzbekistan",
      "cases":8,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Guyana",
      "cases":7,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":1,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Ukraine",
      "cases":7,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":1,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Liechtenstein",
      "cases":7,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Rwanda",
      "cases":7,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Channel Islands",
      "cases":6,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Ghana",
      "cases":6,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Guadeloupe",
      "cases":6,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Honduras",
      "cases":6,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Cameroon",
      "cases":5,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Ethiopia",
      "cases":5,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Puerto Rico",
      "cases":5,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Ivory Coast",
      "cases":4,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Cuba",
      "cases":4,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Mongolia",
      "cases":4,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Trinidad and Tobago",
      "cases":4,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"DRC",
      "cases":3,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"French Polynesia",
      "cases":3,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Gibraltar",
      "cases":3,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":1,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Guam",
      "cases":3,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Kenya",
      "cases":3,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"St. Barth",
      "cases":3,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Seychelles",
      "cases":3,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Nigeria",
      "cases":2,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":1,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Aruba",
      "cases":2,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Curaçao",
      "cases":2,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Namibia",
      "cases":2,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Saint Lucia",
      "cases":2,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Saint Martin",
      "cases":2,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Cayman Islands",
      "cases":1,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":1,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Sudan",
      "cases":1,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":1,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Nepal",
      "cases":1,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":1,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Antigua and Barbuda",
      "cases":1,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Bahamas",
      "cases":1,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Benin",
      "cases":1,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Bhutan",
      "cases":1,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"CAR",
      "cases":1,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Congo",
      "cases":1,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Equatorial Guinea",
      "cases":1,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Gabon",
      "cases":1,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Greenland",
      "cases":1,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Guinea",
      "cases":1,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Vatican City",
      "cases":1,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Liberia",
      "cases":1,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Mauritania",
      "cases":1,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Mayotte",
      "cases":1,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"St. Vincent Grenadines",
      "cases":1,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Somalia",
      "cases":1,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Suriname",
      "cases":1,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Eswatini",
      "cases":1,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Tanzania",
      "cases":1,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"Togo",
      "cases":1,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   },
   {
      "country":"U.S. Virgin Islands",
      "cases":1,
      "todayCases":0,
      "deaths":0,
      "todayDeaths":0,
      "recovered":0,
      "critical":0
   }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "todaysCases"]
```

should be

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "todayCases"]
```

The same with `todaysDeaths`